# Printing movieclip with margin

Tags: printing, actionscript-2, margin, movieclip

Could someone help me to print a movie clip with custom margin for the paper(A4). I figured the as2 for print.How could I set margin for the print.?

```
btnPrint.onPress = function()
{
var pj = new PrintJob();
var success = pj.start();
if (success)
{
    //Centered Variables
    var mc_width:Number = _root.my_mc._width / 2;
    var mc_height:Number = _root.my_mc._height / 2;

    var xHalfMax:Number = (pj.pageWidth / 2);
    var yHalfMax:Number = (pj.pageHeight / 2);
    var xHalfMin:Number = xHalfMax * -1;
    var yHalfMin:Number = yHalfMax * -1;

    pj.addPage("game",{xMin:xHalfMin, xMax:xHalfMax, yMin:yHalfMin,   yMax:yHalfMax});
    pj.send();
}
delete pj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a page movie clip that depicts the entire page and then layout the elements on the page often either copying or moving elements from the game to the page or creating new elements. This allows you to manipulate the print elements a bit because they are often not printed exactly the same as the appear in the game.

This layout includes the full page area with margins and is sized for the paper. This movie clip page is then scalable for different page sizes. I then send this page to the print job.